# CMake seems to ignore CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm using CMake 3.3.2 and Xcode 7.1 on OS X 10.10.5.

I have a small C++ project that uses CMake. I want it to run on OS X 10.9 or later. So I modified my CMakeLists.txt to look start this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.9")

project(...
```

Then I create the Xcode project like this:

```
cmake -G Xcode <path>
```

However, the resulting xcodeproj bundle doesn't seem to have a deployment target set. When I open the contained project.pbxproj file in a text editor, there is no line mentioning `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

Accordingly, when I open the project in Xcode, under Build Settings > Deployment > OS X Deployment Target, Xcode always displays the default value "OS X 10.11", no matter what I specify in CMakeLists.txt. When I manually change the setting in Xcode and then re-open the project file in a text editor, the line `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9;` has correctly been added.

Am I doing something wrong? Googling the problem didn't give any recent results.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The variable [`CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html) must initialized as a cache variable prior to the first `project()` command in order for the Xcode project generation to be picked up properly:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.9" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")
```

If not set explicitly as a *cache* variable the `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is initialized by the [`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html) environment variable.

The initialization of a cache variable like in the assignment above will also override the value of non-cache variables of the same name in the same scope.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot! What I don't understand though is why the value needs to be cached. I didn't find any mention in the documentation of CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET. Is there a general rule regarding caching that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The official docs mention that "if not set explicitly the value is initialized by the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET environment variable" but fail to mention that only a cached variable is regarded as an explicit value.