# Why are MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED and MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED no longer being honored after upgrading to macOS Sierra/Xcode 8?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My libui project must both compile on and target OS X 10.8 and newer, so I have

```
#define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_8
#define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_8
```

in the shared header file for the Cocoa code. So far this has worked; I've seen nothing about functions deprecated after 10.9. However, after upgrading to 10.12 and Xcode 8 last night, I am suddenly seeing a whole bunch of deprecation warnings, such as

```
/Users/pietro/src/github.com/andlabs/libui/darwin/entry.m:181:28: warning: 
      'NSRegularControlSize' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.12
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        uiDarwinSetControlFont(t, NSRegularControlSize);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  NSControlSizeRegular
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSCell.h:102:28: note: 
      'NSRegularControlSize' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
static const NSControlSize NSRegularControlSize API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPL...
                           ^
```

as if the macros I provided are being ignored. I tried to figure out what's going on, and I'm just getting mixed signals: some sources on Apple's developer site tell me it's really __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED (and use a number instead of a symbolic constant for the version itself), while others tell me I'm right. Some sources seem to imply these values are determined by the compiler settings? And I can't tell what Availability.h wants anymore.

For what it's worth, this project uses CMake to build, and doesn't use Xcode projects directly.

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you including AvailabilityMacros.h ? https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.1.32/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/AvailabilityMacros.h.auto.html

Comment: Isn't that automatically included with `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`?

Comment: Is your deployment target set to < 10.12 in the build settings?

Comment: @Wevah Yes, it is 10.8, done with `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8")`.

Comment: Oh right, you're building with CMake. I derped that line.

Comment: @Paurian I did a bit more research: `AvailabilityMacros.h` is still being included, and I imagine it's still working properly. There's something different about *these* new names in particular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh. The problem is CMake being stupid.

Okay, so it turns out all these new deprecation systems *are* documented, but in a roundabout way. First, the new deprecation macros are [mentioned here in the 10.12 SDK release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/). If I look in Availability.h, where they are defined, I see they are expanded to a new `availability` attribute in clang. And lo and behold, [they are controlled by the `-mmacosx-deployment-target` option after all](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#availability).

But wait, I had

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8")
```

in my CMakeLists.txt. Shouldn't that be enough? Apparently not, because the `-mmacosx-version-min` wasn't being put in the Makefiles!

[As it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208360/cmake-seems-to-ignore-cmake-osx-deployment-target), `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is one of those stupid CMake variables that require you to `CACHE STRING "" FORCE` the actual `set()` for them to work. So once I changed the line to

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

the deprecation warnings went away. Why are so many of these CMake variables insistent on being cached like this? Is `set()` not good enough? And why do I need to `FORCE` the caching; is even `CACHE` not good enough? :| It's a shame trying to maintain libui with pure Makefiles proved to be too unwieldy and that CMake was the option most people wanted. :/

---

Of course, the deprecation warnings are gone, but that doesn't lead us all the way there, because some of the constants that were renamed were left in as `static const` variables. Which means I can't say

```
case NSKeyUp:
```

in a `switch` statement without a warning about standards compliance, since that technically isn't allowed in C99 (`const` is just a hint to the compiler) and I explicitly disable GNU language extensions (mostly personal preference). I don't think it's allowed in C++ either (in fact, I'm pretty sure C++11 introduced `constexpr` for this reason), but once I verify that I'm going to file a radar on this issue. I'll update this answer with more details as they come.

Thanks for all your help in the meantime!

Comment: Could you provide an example? I just set both compiler flag `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(-mmacosx-version-min=10.10)` and `SET(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.10" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`, but nothing has changed. I use CMake 3.20.2.

Answer (score 2):

I've always set those with compiler flags: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.8`. CMake also has a `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` variable which I think sets that.

I don't think it will get rid of those deprecation warnings though. For those deprecated AppKit constants, both the deprecated and new constants have the same value. You can use the new constants, the value is the same and it should be binary-compatible back to older OSes.

Using the new constants *will* prevent the code from compiling on systems older than 10.12 though. emacs [fixed this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-08/msg00358.html) by using the new constants in the code, but `#defining` the old ones to the new ones when compiling with a pre-10.12 SDK. I [implemented the same thing](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/4ba967ad7454c08d7e01b047d34d0c3d98f2a10d#diff-1fdc5419bda303ee3f720fb8ccdab2c3) for `qemu`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read/respond to this thoroughly later (when I have more time), but I will say I already do have `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8")` in my CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Also I wonder if the `-mmacosx-version-min` flag or whatever else CMake produces there (I forget the specifics now, sorry) only affect the object file and linking steps.

Comment: Actually I just noticed something: some of the deprecation warnings are on `static const` variables, which means I can't use them in `switch` statements in ISO C99 mode without a warning anyway. I'm tempted to just open a radar at this point, if only so I could potentially learn from the source what the current macros should be, or if the open-source code you linked is my only real option... (I was hoping I could use a different SDK, but I only seem to have 10.12.sdk now.)

Comment: Each warning should tell you what the replacement macro is, and you can also see in the headers to see how they're defined. For example, `NSControlSizeRegular` (the new one) is defined in an NS_ENUM, and then the deprecated `NSRegularControlSize` is `static const NSControlSize NSRegularControlSize = NSControlSizeRegular;`
Using the new one shouldn't have the same `static const` problem.

Comment: It would not, but it would break compilation on older systems, hence those open source projects you linked having to make their own `#define`s.

Comment: Yeah, true. There's no master list anywhere of #defines from old constants to new, you'll just need to build on an older OS (VMs are useful for this) or with an old SDK copied into Xcode and fix the errors. [xcodelegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) might be helpful if you want to try an old SDK

Comment: Okay, more stuff: `/Users/pietro/src/github.com/andlabs/libui/darwin/stddialogs.m:83:15: warning: 'beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.10 - Use -beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler: instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]` So even for methods the new macros are ignored. I guess I'll have to make two separate radars then, because I'm not sure what to do about this.