# Why the CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET not work when using cmake generate xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I developed a CMake project to generate an Xcode project, where I want to set the deployment target to macOS 10.12, so I add

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.12" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")
```

in my CMakeLists.txt, following the [CMake seems to ignore CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208360/cmake-seems-to-ignore-cmake-osx-deployment-target).
When rebuilding the CMake project, the deployment target in the generated Xcode project is not set  to macos 10.12, but to the default 10.14, which I did not expect.

How can I fix it, so that the Xcode project deployment target uses the CMake setting?

Comment: Could you please provide your full `CMakeLists.txt`, or at least a [mcve]!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had tried multiple times and find the solution:
just add the 'FORCE' end the set() syntax

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.12" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version" FORCE)
```

Hope it can help someone!

Comment: Yes, It actually helped me ! I wonder about the `FORCE` requirement here and what make the setting to be ignored otherwise... Perhaps did you find out why ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve it not using `FORCE`.

Two solutions:

1. Put your `set` command before the first `project()` command.
2. Just use `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.12")`, removing `CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version"`, if your `set` command need to be after the first `project()` command.

In the [CMake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html#:%7E:text=In%20CMake%20there%20are%20two,not%20persisted%20across%20CMake%20runs.) says:

> In CMake there are two types of variables: normal variables and cache variables. Normal variables are meant for the internal use of the script (just like variables in most programming languages); they are not persisted across CMake runs. Cache variables (unless set with INTERNAL) are mostly intended for configuration settings where **the first CMake run determines a suitable default value**, which the user can then override, by editing the cache with tools such as ccmake or cmake-gui. Cache variables are stored in the CMake cache file, and are persisted across CMake runs.

In other words, with `CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version"`, CMake will set `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to a value [computed based on the host platform](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html), aka your computer. This will happen **in the first `project()` command**.

So if your `set` command is before the first `project()` command, you could use your full command with `CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version"`.

But if your `set` command is after `project()` command, then your `set` would not set `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` any more. You need remove the `CACHE ....`

And that's why if you add `FORCE` in the end, it will work, like the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55294037/9522354) suggested.

`FORCE` means ignore cache and set variable forcely. But the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) says that **it should normally be avoided**:

> If FORCE is specified, the value of the cache variable is set, even if the variable is already in the cache. This should normally be avoided, as it will remove any changes to the cache variable’s value by the user.